# Какой тип schema.org использовать для landing page?

Tags: seo, schema.org, микроразметка

Есть `landing page` на котором находится информация о конкретном товаре (4 вида одной позиции) который производит предприятие, калькулятор расчета стоимости и контактные данные. Какая схема будет правильной? И можно ли использовать 2 разные схемы на 1 странице?

Answer (score 2):

Товар может быть структурирован с данными для типа **[Product](https://schema.org/Product)**. Это соответствует рекомендациям Гугл для структурированных данных: "*Данные должны представлять главное содержание вебстраницы*".

> И можно ли использовать 2 разные схемы на 1 странице?

Это может использоваться, опять же если главное содержание имеет два различных субъекта. Однако, если субъект веб-страницы только один, то два различных типа будут конкурировать и делить сок между собой. К тому же поисковику будет трудно или даже невозможно определить релевантный тип данных для конкретного поискового запроса.